# AudioConverterNew returned -50

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, core-audio

I have a little issue regarding the use of the AudioQueue services.
I have followed the guide that is available on Apple's webiste, but when I got to start and run the Audio Queue, I get the message telling me that "AudioConverterNew returned -50".
Now, I know that the -50 error code means that there is a bad parameter. However, what I don't know is which parameter is the bad one (thank you so much Apple...) !

---

So, here's my code.

Here are the parameters of my class, named cPlayerCocoa

```
AudioQueueRef                   mQueue;
AudioQueueBufferRef             mBuffers[NUMBER_BUFFERS];    // NUMBER_BUFFERS = 3
uint32                          mBufferByteSize;
AudioStreamBasicDescription     mDataFormat;
```

Here's the first function :

```
static void
BuildBuffer( void* iAQData, AudioQueueRef iAQ, AudioQueueBufferRef iBuffer )
{
    cPlayerCocoa* player = (cPlayerCocoa*) iAQData;
    player->HandleOutputBuffer( iAQ, iBuffer );
}
```

It creates a cPlayerCocoa from the structure containing the AudioQueue and calls the HandleOutputBuffer function, which allocates the audio buffers :

```
void
cPlayerCocoa::HandleOutputBuffer( AudioQueueRef iAQ, AudioQueueBufferRef iBuffer )
{
    if( mContinue )
    {
        xassert( iBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize == 32768 );
        int startSample = mPlaySampleCurrent;
        int result = 0;

        int samplecount = 32768 / ( mSoundData->BytesPerSample() );    // BytesPerSample, in my case, returns 4
        tErrorCode  error = mSoundData->ReadData( (int16*)(iBuffer->mAudioData), samplecount, &result, startSample );

        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer( mQueue, iBuffer, 0, 0 );    // I'm using CBR data (PCM), hence the 0 passed into the AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer.
        if( result != samplecount )
            mContinue = false;
        startSample += result;
    }      
    else
    {
        AudioQueueStop( mQueue, false );
    }
}
```

In this next function, the AudioQueue is created then started.
I begin to initialise the parameters of the Data format. Then I create the AudioQueue, and I allocate the 3 buffers.
When the buffers are allocated, I start the AudioQueue and then I run the loop.

```
void
cPlayerCocoa::ThreadEntry()
{
    int samplecount = 32768 / ( mSoundData->BytesPerSample() );
    mDataFormat.mSampleRate = mSoundData->SamplingRate();    // Returns 44100
    mDataFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    mDataFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 32768;
    mDataFormat.mFramesPerPacket = samplecount;
    mDataFormat.mBytesPerFrame = mSoundData->BytesPerSample();    // BytesPerSample returns 4.
    mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    mDataFormat.mBitsPerChannel = uint32(mSoundData->BitsPerChannel());
    mDataFormat.mReserved = 0;

    AudioQueueNewOutput( &mDataFormat, BuildBuffer, this, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &mQueue );
    for( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_BUFFERS; ++i )
    {
        AudioQueueAllocateBuffer( mQueue, mBufferByteSize, &mBuffers[i] );
        HandleOutputBuffer( mQueue, mBuffers[i] );
    }

    AudioQueueStart( mQueue, NULL );    // I want the queue to start playing immediately, so I pass NULL
    do {
        CFRunLoopRunInMode( kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.25, false );
    } while ( !NeedStopASAP() );

    AudioQueueDispose( mQueue, true );
}
```

---

The call to AudioQueueStart returns -50 (bad parameter) and I can't figure what's wrong...
I would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You could start by checking the results of all the calls that return an `OSStatus`.

Comment: The title of this question says AudioConverterNew fails, but the body asks about AudioQueueStart.  Where is the message from AudioConverterNew generated?

Comment: @molbdnilo As I have already explained, -50 returns "Bad parameter".

Comment: @sbooth It is generated when AudioQueueStart is called.

Comment: @ThierryCantet Yes, but you never ensure that everything you did up to that point succeeded. Apple's guide deliberately excludes error handling, but that's only to keep the examples short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your ASBD is suspect.  PCM formats have predictable values for `mBytesPerPacket`, `mBytesPerFrame`, and `mFramesPerPacket`.  For normal 16-bit interleaved signed 44.1 stereo audio the ASBD would look like

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd = {
  .mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
  .mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked,
  .mSampleRate = 44100,
  .mChannelsPerFrame = 2,
  .mBitsPerChannel = 16,
  .mBytesPerPacket = 4,
  .mFramesPerPacket = 1,
  .mBytesPerFrame = 4,
  .mReserved = 0
};
```

`AudioConverterNew` returns -50 when one of the ASBDs is unsupported.  There is no PCM format where `mBytesPerPacket` should be 32768, which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: I have similar issue, Can you please check it out?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959554/audioqueue-callback-get-empty-buffer-on-ios-7-only